# DOM not printing nodeValue of an id

Tags: javascript, php, dom

I am printing Google plus share count of google website. My coding:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = strtolower(file_get_contents("https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/+1/fastbutton?count=true&url=http://google.com"));
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();
echo $dom->getElementById('aggregateCount')->nodeValue;
```

I am getting this output:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\start\test.php on line 7
```

When i pass this html directly, it's work.

```
$html = "<html><head></head><body><div id='aggregateCount'>node value</div></body></html>";
```

Comment: $dom is not an object, so, maybe, it doesn't load correctly the html

Comment: Does `file_get_contents` return your html successfully? If not then dom is not loaded in `$html` so tyring to get property `nodeValue` of non-object.

Comment: drop the `strtolower` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `strtolower` on your HTML when doing a `file_get_contents`. But not when you read the string directly.

Comment: yes, You are right. i am using this id **aggregateCount** after apply **strtolower function**. I should remove **strtolower function** else apply **strtolower function** to id **aggregateCount**. Thank you